# Unrecognized base64 character: {

Tags: base64

I need to have a JSON Formatted Base64 for this, but I am not sure how to change this string to have it as Base64 JSON Format.

```
public  String requestBody =  '{["Um05dkxFSmhjZz09"]}';
```

Um05dkxFSmhjZz09 this is already in Base64

Comment: *Why* do you need your JSON to be base64?

Comment: @AdrianLarson its for my test class Fake respond, and I receive String M = (String)JSON.deserializeStrict(responseBody,String.class);
        b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(M);  in my class, so my test string needs to be in that format

Comment: I am really confused with data structure inside string, it looks like a Hash Map without key but an array

Comment: @karthikselva its a fake response

Comment: do you want to create Base64 encoded value of 'Um05dkxFSmhjZz09'?? or the whole String '{["Um05dkxFSmhjZz09"]}'?

Comment: How do you format Um05dkxFSmhjZz09 into a JSON Respond format? [Um05dkxFSmhjZz09] I have tried few different ways its not working

Comment: @SanTosh Only Um05dkxFSmhjZz09 ... that is already based64

Comment: Also, this base 64 is double encoded.  `decode(decode('Um05dkxFSmhjZz09')) == 'Foo,Bar'`

Comment: @PhilRymek yes, lol that is very smart. I didnt think anyone would go after the decode :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in test cases we can actually use Base64 and do

```
String formatJSON = JSON.serializePretty(requestBody);
```

to turn it into Json

Answer (score 2):

> **Encoding/Decoding** is different from **Serialization/Deserialization**

- The JSON you have for fake response is malformed.
- If all you are getting from the response is Base64 encoded string, you don't need to deserialize
- So in this case there is no need for JSON at all

Try this instead:

```
public String requestBody =  'Um05dkxFSmhjZz09';
b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(requestBody);
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond I just use this to make it JSON String formatJSON = JSON.serializePretty(requestBody);

Answer (score 1):

A JSON works in a **key-value pair**.

When you are creating JSON here, I see the value, but not the key. Hence the solution would be to create a key-value pair instead.

Like:

```
public  String requestBody =  '{"yourkey": "Um05dkxFSmhjZz09"}'  //This is a JSON String
```

If you intend to use an array of values, use:

```
public  String requestBody =  '{"yourkeys": ["Um05dkxFSmhjZz09"]}'
```

and to validate any JSON in future, you could always use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Thankyou for the respond , I actually didnt know I could make it format it to json by String formatJSON = JSON.serializePretty(requestBody); it worked just fine

Comment: great! good to know :)

Comment: I posted the answer as well , I am not sure if its okay, but you gave a lot of good information thank you

Comment: its perfectly OK. you can mark your answer as best answer after 2 days... :)